# Redefining class member data types

Tags: c++, types, c++17, discriminated-union

Is it possible to change the data type of a class member after its initialization? Say, redefine a double named "Foo" to a string?

Comment: You should think again about your design. There are common cases to have container types which can keep different data types. But a class which "needs" to have one of two different types sounds a bit unusual. Maybe an XY-problem?

Comment: Hey @Klaus. The specific situation is that I'm working on a Matrix class. The functionality I've implemented (like calculating the determinant) only works for symmetrical matrices at the moment (2x2, 3x3, etc.). So for some objects, the determinant can't be calculated. My problem then is, say, preventing the retrieval of an undefined determinant variable incorrectly as 0 (which could be a result).

Comment: @AlexanderSwanson [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is your friend in situations like that.

Comment: Then you should think about the return type of the method. std::optional is a potential solution. It can return a value or left "clear". So you have a optional correct answer stored in it or if no answer is possible the bool conversion is false.

Comment: Yes! I have considered `std::optional`, @MilesBudnek and @Klaus . However, for whatever reason, my IDE cannot find the library in my C++ installation. I've just found out that it cannot find `std::variant` either, which @AndyG suggested. So I'm going to have to do some digging to see why I cannot access these libraries...

Comment: Have you c++17 support? If not, you can simply use a std::tuple<bool, double> and set the bool part as flag for "valid answer" and use double ( or every other type you like ) as value. Or maybe you can use boost::variant

Comment: Hmm, that's could definitely work, @Klaus! However, I'd really like to use `std::optional`, it seems like the best way. I certainly have C++ 17 support... I think I'll just try a reinstall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer to your comment, you should use `std::optional`

```
std::optional<int> Do(int x, int y)
{   
    if ( x == y ) 
    {
        return 42; 
    }

    return {}; 
}   

int main()
{   
    auto ret = Do(3,2); // << exchange your test data here!
    if ( ret ) 
    {   
        std::cout << "Got an answer" << ret.value() << std::endl;
    }   
    else
    {   
        std::cout << "No answer" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for this, @Klaus. This is perfect. Just gotta figure out what's going on with my C++ installation now.

Answer (score 3):

No. Types are fixed at compile time. If you want to switch between double and a string perhaps reach for a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
std::variant<double, std::string> val = 1.0;
val = std::string("hello");
```

Comment: @AlexanderSwanson: It's well worth the read :-) They are stored as efficiently as possible, and accessing them involves an inversion of control via a visitor pattern, so client code doesn't typically say "if it's a string, do X, else if it's a double, do Y". It instead says "Here's a function to run if it's a string. Here's a function to run if it's a double. Do your thing"